# Get the count of users in a month from MySQL date

Tags: mysql, sql, spring-boot

I want to display registered users each month on my web app. To achieve this I suppose to query the count from the user's table and send it to the front end. As an example, I get the count of users in one month from the following query.

```
select count(u_id) AS 'Count', MONTH(reg_date) AS Month
from user
WHERE(reg_date) BETWEEN '2019-10-01' AND '2019-10-31'
```

This displays the number of users registered in October. The resulting table I get from this query is this.

```
------------------------
Count            Month
------------------------
2                10
------------------------
```

The result I want to get is the following one.

```
------------------------
Count            Month
------------------------
2                1
------------------------
10               2
------------------------
5               3
------------------------
```

I have stored the user ID and register date in the user table. register date is SQL date type and UserID is Integer. I can get the number of users in a given month using the query I have mentioned below and store it in a variable in backend and call again database to get the next month and so on(Using a loop). Then create a list and send to the frontend. But for this I have to call the database several times. For getting the users of 12 months I have to query 12 times.
What I want is to get the number of users in each month from just one query. If I store the date as three columns like date, month, year I can get this result. But I do not wish to change the current table structure. Is there any way to approach this task without changing the current table sturcture?

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for is GROUP BY.

```
SELECT count(u_id) AS 'Count', MONTH(reg_date) AS Month
from user
WHERE(reg_date) BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-31'
GROUP BY YEAR(reg_date), MONTH(reg_date);
```

Comment: What happens if the OP's happens to be completely missing one or more months?

Comment: @timbiegeleisen that would be a display issue, most elegantly resolved in application code

Answer (score 3):

First is to generate `months 1 to 12`, then `join` your original query based on `month`.

```
select t1.monthNo,  t2.Count
from (select 1 as monthNo
    union
    select 2 as monthNo
    union
    select 3 as monthNo
    union
    select 4 as monthNo
    union
    select 5 as monthNo
    union
    select 6 as monthNo
    union
    select 7 as monthNo
    union
    select 8 as monthNo
    union
    select 9 as monthNo
    union
    select 10 as monthNo
    union
    select 11 as monthNo
    union
    select 12 as monthNo) as t1
left join 
    (select count(u_id) AS 'Count', month(reg_date) AS Month
    from user   
    group by month(reg_date)) t2 on t2.Month = t1.monthNo
```

Comment: @Metal I have to create a new table which contains 12 months, right ?

Comment: no need, just copy entire t1 (subquery) as your months

Comment: @Pegasus008, this dbfiddle might help. https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=82qGuyLQn4

Comment: I think should add a `WHERE YEAR(reg_date)=**year**` to prevent overlapping years

Comment: @tcadidot0, yes I agree, grouping should be by year-month if selection is not within the year